# Problem with the shape of the output array

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm currently writing my master thesis and need some help to find the mistake.

First, a short explination of my code:

1. The data for my neural network is created in a database and loaded into the Project via the array data_storage.
2. In the Project I separate the last column (target class) and normalize all values. This creates the arrays input_data and output_data.
3. Due to the small amount of data I use cross-validation and split both arrays in the same ratio into training and test data.
4. Each cross validation step opens a method in which a new neural network is created and trained several times. Each time the function get the new sorted data. The neural network and the evaluation result are then returned to the main part of the program. There they are added to a list.
5. When the cross-validation is finished, the individual results of the passes (= each list instance) are averaged.
6. Code is not finished at the moment.

My neural network should have 9 classes like the scenarios I have labeled in the database. But there is a problem with the shape which first appears during the fit process.

My code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Apr  3 16:26:14 2019

@author: mattdoe
"""

from data_preprocessor_db import data_storage # validation data
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical, normalize
from tensorflow.keras.models  import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from numpy import array

# create and evaluate a single multi-layer-perzeptron
def evaluate_model(Train, Test, Target_Train, Target_Test):
    # define model
    model = Sequential()
    # input layer automatically created
    model.add(Dense(9, input_dim=9, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')) # 1st hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(9, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu')) # 2nd hidden layer
    model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax')) #output layer

    # create model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    # fit model
    model.fit(Train, to_categorical(Target_Train), epochs=50, verbose=0)

    # evaluate the model
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(Test, to_categorical(Target_Test), verbose=0)

    # as well: create a confussion matrix
    predicted = model.predict(Test)
    conf_mat = confusion_matrix(Target_Test, predicted)

    return model, test_acc, conf_mat

# for seperation of data_storage
# Link_ID = []
Input_data, Output_data = list(), list()

# list all results of k-fold cross-validation
scores, members, matrix = list(), list(), list()

# seperate data_storage in Input and Output data
for items in data_storage:
    # Link_ID = items[0] # identifier not needed
    Input_data.append([items[1], items[2], items[3], items[4], items[5], items[6], items[7], items[8], items[9]]) # Input: all characteristics
    Output_data.append(items[10]) # Output: scenario_class 1 to 8

# change to numpy_array (scalar index array)
Input_data = array(Input_data)
Output_data = array(Output_data)

# normalize Data
Input_data = normalize(Input_data)
# Output = normalize(Output) not needed; categorical number

# prepare k-fold cross-validation
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=15, random_state=1, shuffle=True)

for train_ix, test_ix in kfold.split(Input_data, Output_data):
    # select samples
    Train, Target_Train = Input_data[train_ix], Output_data[train_ix]
    Test, Target_Test = Input_data[test_ix], Output_data[test_ix]

    # evaluate model
    model, test_acc, conf_mat = evaluate_model(Train, Test, Target_Train, Target_Test)

    # display each evalution result
    print('>%.3f' % test_acc)

    # add result to list
    scores.append(test_acc)
    members.append(model)
    matrix.append(conf_mat)

# summarize expected performance
print('Estimated Accuracy %.3f (%.3f)' % (mean(scores), std(scores)))
# as well in confursion_matrix
print ('Confussion Matrix %' %(mean(matrix)))

# save model // trained neuronal network
model.save('neuronal_network_1.h5')
```

My error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-25afb095a816>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Workspace/Master-Thesis/Programm/MapValidationML/ml_neuronal_network_1.py', wdir='C:/Workspace/Master-Thesis/Programm/MapValidationML')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Workspace/Master-Thesis/Programm/MapValidationML/ml_neuronal_network_1.py", line 76, in <module>
    model, test_acc, conf_mat = evaluate_model(Train, Test, Target_Train, Target_Test)

  File "C:/Workspace/Master-Thesis/Programm/MapValidationML/ml_neuronal_network_1.py", line 33, in evaluate_model
    model.fit(Train, to_categorical(Target_Train), epochs=50, verbose=0)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 643, in fit
    use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 632, in fit
    shuffle=shuffle)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 2469, in _standardize_user_data
    y, self._feed_loss_fns, feed_output_shapes)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 685, in check_loss_and_target_compatibility
    ' while using as loss `' + loss_name + '`. '

ValueError: A target array with shape (847, 10) was passed for an output of shape (None, 9) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

Comment: There are 9 labels but the target array contains 10 labels.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand why my target array has 10 labels.

So in my database are some records stored in that way:

Answer (score 0):

@Shubman Panchal: Yes, you're right, but I don't understand why my target array has 10 labels.

So in my database are some records (perhaps 800) stored in that way:

```
id|info1|info2|info3|info4|info5|info6|info7|info8|info9|class
--------------------------------------------------------------
1|0.2|0.7|4|2|6|8|1|7.2|8|1
2|0.7|0.4|5|3|5|4|2|3|6.4|5
.........
800|0|0|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|7
```

Those records are labeled from 1 to 9.

In my program I load all records into the list variable data_storage.
Then I split this variable/every records in Input_data(info1...info9) and Output_data(class), delete the id by the way.

Input_data and Output_data are a list of items at the beginning either.
So there are 800 tuples stored, e. g. for ID = 1: `(0.2,0.7,4,2,6,8,1,7.2,8)` as an item in the list Input_data and `(1)` as an item in the list Output_data.

After that I change the type from list to array and expect that every list item is a row now. I will check the format of this array...

At the end, the values of the array becomes normalized.

Does anyone have an idea?